# What is the definition of Yudhishtira Saka and when does it start with respect to the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, history, yudhisthira

Yudhisthira Saka is used in many historical texts. Can anyone tell what is the context behind this Saka and the start of the Saka with respect to Mahabharata war?